# How to remove nesting from Django REST Framework serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models defined in my `models.py` file:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    band = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

For these, I have defined the serializers in my `serializers.py` file as:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = "__all__"


class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album = AlbumSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = "__all__"
```

When I make a request, the data I get is in this format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "album": {
            "id": 1,
            "album": "Hybrid Theory",
            "band": "Linkin Park"
        },
        "song": "Numb"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "album": {
            "id": 1,
            "album": "Hybrid Theory",
            "band": "Linkin Park"
        },
        "song": "In the End"
    }
]
```

How do I remove the nesting from the album name, from the songs Serializer? I would want data something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "album_id": 1,
        "album": "Hybrid Theory",
        "band": "Linkin Park"
        "song": "Numb"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "album_id": 1,
        "album": "Hybrid Theory",
        "band": "Linkin Park"
        "song": "In the End"
    }
]
```

Comment: you can override `to_representation()` to get a different behaviour of your data that you want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SongSerializer

1. remove `album = AlbumSerializer()`
2. override method `to_representation`

```py
from django.forms import model_to_dict

def to_representation(self, instance):
        song = super().to_representation(instance)
        album = model_to_dict(instance.album)
        for key, value in album.items():
           setattr(song, key, value)
        return song
```

I did not test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='album.id')
    album = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='album.album')
    band = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='album.band')

    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = ['album_id', 'album', 'band', .....]
```